# DropDownList Not Displaying Umlauts Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode

I'm a little stumped as to why when I manually set a DropDownList's ListItem like:

```
li.Text = "- Auswählen -";
```

it shows up like the following:
[image]

The HTML's meta tag has charset="utf-8", so I'm a little confused.

Comment: try adding the ListItem in the html and see, if it work!

Comment: @Jaypal - Unfortunately I can't do that because I'm overwriting the text in existing items in some custom generated controls, so it can't be done in HTML directly.

Comment: sounds like in the code behind you will need to create a new instance of the `li` object and from there try to assign the text.. but can't tell what you're truly trying to do without seeing more relevant code. can you show how you are initially populating the control(s)

Comment: does it happen with any borwser

Comment: Take a look in VS under `File > Advanced save options...` if your page is saved as Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add below lines on Global.asax file then check.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Equals("text/xml"))
     {
          Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
     }
}
```